# Force refresh the GUI of an individual application

Tags: unity, gui, rhythmbox

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity 7.2.6.

Periodically various applications when they are being restored from being minimized don't render the app's interface. Minimizing, maximizing to full screen doesn't help. It is necessary to close such applications and then reopen them in order to continue using them. I'll give as an example a screenshot of Rhythmbox that shows nothing in the Rhythmbox window but a blank screen:

[image]

How to cope with this problem? Is there a way to force redrawing the application's GUI on the screen? Because there are occasions when one might need to view/copy from or save the data from the application before closing it.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things you could try is to backup package-related configuration files and data that you don't want them to get removed during "purge".

Then purge package, then install package again.

```
apt purge <packagename>
apt install <packagename>
```

As a general advice, make sure you have the latest upgrades by issuing

```
apt update
apt upgrade
```

Slightly offtopic: you can consider switching to more recent LTS(16.04), it might be that problem you encountered(and many more) are already got their fixes in Xenial.

Comment: Thanks for answer! But this does not solve the problem. And yes, on 16.04 this problem remains =\